# Не прогружается дизайн приложения xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Проблема заключается в том, что приложение на xamarin'е не прогружается от слова совсем. Оно успешно собирается, развертывается на устройстве(для отладки использую Android,т.к на эмулятор мощности ноута не хватает), но вижу после развертывания только белый экран, а на мониторе ни одной ошибки. В чем причина и как её устранить?

PS Что самое странное, оно перестало отрисовываться после того, как я добавил собственную логику в конструктор MainPage, до её добавления все прорисовывалось успешно

PPS Такое происходит на устройствах независимо от их версий. Запускал на android'ах  версий 8.1 и 10.0

Дополнение(Добавил OnApearing,но только новые ошибки вылезли):[image: Добавил, только новые ошибки вылезли]

xaml-код:[image: разметка]

Comment: К конструкторе никто никогда не добавляет свою логику. Есть `OnAppearing`, который выполняется перед показом страницы. [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48183940/12888024) Покажите ваш код, который вы добавили.

Comment: код:     justPicker.Items.Add("RU");
            justPicker.Items.Add("EN"); 
            justPicker.Items.Add("ES");

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, целиком, а не только эти 3 строчки.

Comment: Это весь код, который я добавлял. У меня тестовое приложение.

Comment: покажите xaml разметку и код в вопросе, я без понятия, что такое justPicker

Comment: Как я понял, перенос кода в `OnAppearing` не помог, так?

Comment: aepot, ещё проверяю)

Comment: `но только новые ошибки вылезли` эти ошибки никак не относятся к тому, что вы добавили в `OnAppearing`.